# export 'component' (imported as 'component') was not found in 'react' (possible exports:

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React, {component} from 'react';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MyTestFunction from './components/MyTestFunction'

class App extends component {

  render(){
    return(
      <div className="App">
        <h1 />


         </div>
    );
  }
}
    
   export default App;
```

Comment: C in `component` should be capital "C".

Comment: Thanks @HanchenJiang....Problem get resolved ...!!

Answer (score 2):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
```

It is case senitive